# Selecting all text nodes in between two processing instructions with XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, marklogic

I have some following XML:

```
<content>
  <p>
    <?change-addition-start?>
    test 
    <em>test</em>
    <strong>test</strong>
    <?change-addition-end?>
  </p>
</content>
```

I am trying to add an `<ins>` tag after the `<?change-addition-start?>` PI, and a closing `</ins>` tag before the `<?change-addition-end?>`, so basically just trying to wrap anything between those two PI's in an `<ins>` tag. Is there a way to achieve this with XSLT/XPATH? There can be any content in between those tags, so setting up something specific to my test case above will not be possible.

Comment: It seems like a text book example for XSLT 2 `for-each-group group-starting-with` with a nested `for-each-group group-ending-with` so see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info or your favourite intro to grouping in XSLT 2. XQuery 3 with tumbling window start/end conditions should also do it.

Comment: Of course if you know there will be just those two processing instructions then in XPath 2.0 you can use e.g. `/content/p/processing-instruction('change-addition-start')/following-sibling::node()[. << /content/p/processing-instruction('change-addition-end')]` to select the nodes between the processing instructions.

Comment: @MartinHonnen can you give an example on how this would work in a template? I am getting the following error trying to use your 2nd comment: The value of attribute "match" associated with an element type "xsl:template" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: The pure XPath syntax for the operator is `<<` but inside of XML (XSLT is XML) you need to write `&lt;&lt;` as any `<` not being markup needs to be escaped as `&lt;`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen the following template returns completely empty, any ideas?:    <xsl:template match ="p">
        <ins>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/content/p/processing-instruction('change-addition-start')/following-sibling::node()[. &lt;&lt; /content/p/processing-instruction('change-addition-end')]"/>
        </ins>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: In the context of the `p` I would simplify it to `<xsl:copy-of select="processing-instruction('change-addition-start')/following-sibling::node()[. &lt;&lt; current()/processing-instruction('change-addition-end')]"/>`, as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9Hk12/1, but your code works fine as well at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9Hk12/0 for me.

Comment: I would recommend using grouping instead. There might be content outside of the processing instructions that you don't want to loose. I have done this a lot in the past, like here: https://github.com/grtjn/xproc-ebook-conv/blob/master/src/nl/grtjn/xproc/ebook/build-hierarchy.xsl#L39. I might have time later to adapt it to this case.

Comment: @MartinHonnen would there be a way to achieve this with a template matching on the PI start itself?        <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('start')">
             <ins>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="following-sibling::node()[. &lt;&lt;  $pi-end]"/>
             </ins>
        </xsl:template>

Comment: Here is the update fiddle: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9Hk12/3

Comment: If you match on the pi the other pi is `current()/../processing-instruction(...)` e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="following-sibling::node()[. &lt;&lt; current()/../processing-instruction('change-addition-end')]"/>`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9Hk12/5

Comment: @MartinHonnen I see the output in that latest fiddle erases all the tags which I don't want, is there a way to preserve the tags? Would adding the identity template do that?

Comment: Well, copy the stuff with `xsl:copy-of` or make that mode do what you named it for, so set up an identity transformation for the mode named `copy`. Default processing only copies text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `xal:for-each-group` as suggested in the first comment by Maring Honnen. The other XPath approaches allow you to select the content between two processing instructions, but it will be hard to embed that in an xslt stylesheet that should do other things as well, like copying existing structure at the same time. Here a minimal approach using for-each-group:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $xml :=
  <content>
    <p>
      before
      <?change-addition-start?>
      test 
      <em>test</em>
      <strong>test</strong>
      <?change-addition-end?>
      after
    </p>
  </content>

let $xsl :=
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[processing-instruction()]">
      <xsl:variable name="parent" select="." />

      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::processing-instruction('change-addition-start')">
            <ins>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="identity"/>
            </ins>
          </xsl:when>

          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="identity"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>

return xdmp:xslt-eval($xsl, $xml)
```

Use a second for-each-group with group-ending-by as suggested by Martin if you like to get the end PI **inside** the `<ins>` tag. The above might be sufficient though.

HTH!